# exclude directory clang format

Tags: git, scripting, clang-format

Is there any official directive in `.clang-format` file to exclude directory for applying?

Projects sometimes use `git submodule`, but it is not useful to run `clang-format` over all directory and then use `git checkout` to undo changes in submodule folder.

I have found some related links:

- [Mozilla Source](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/.clang-format-ignore)
- [Github Repo](https://github.com/Sarcasm/run-clang-format)

But they don't seem official.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore files or directories with clang-format 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647960/how-to-ignore-files-or-directories-with-clang-format-3-9)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far, I don't know of any option of clang-format to exclude files or directories. But what I do, is to create the list of files I want to process in a bash script and then call clang-format for them:

```
#!/bin/bash
folder=.
exclude_folder=./submodule
format_files=`find "${folder}" -type f -path "${exclude_folder}" -prune

for file in $format_files
do
  clang-format -i "$file"
done
```

Here the magic is done by the prune option in find. ([How to exclude a directory in find . command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)).

Hope this help you at least.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I think - it is useful solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you can add new _clang-format files (though in this case it looks like you can't?) you can create a new one with

```
DisableFormat: true
SortIncludes: false
```

Obviously this doesn't work if you can't add new _clang-format files :)

Comment: SortIncludes should be set to `Never` instead of false.